# What's wrong with this code? Issue with copying data across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
insert into Permission (UserID, perm, Login) select UserID, 0, Login from Users
```

**What happens**: Copy data across tables and inserts 0 as a default value for 'perm' column. However, I need to run this code every time the software creates its form. So it keeps adding everything it already have.

**Workaround**: DELETE FROM Permission WHERE perm=0 --before running the insert code. This will make sure not to delete users who have Perm=1 (permission to alter something).

**Issue**: So I run the delete code above before running the insert. But since it's a **frequent** routine it will **double** the user already contained in the table Permissions (i.e.: user Admin will have perm=0 and perm=1). Is there anyway to detect if the user already exist and skip it or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is

```
insert into Permission(UserID,perm,Login)
select UserID, 0, Login
from Users
where UserID NOT IN(select UserID from Permission);
```

Basically what that does is inserts them in if they aren't already there.

Comment: Was a tough choice, but your code was the simplest. I like simple things. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: FYI, although the `IN` clause is elegant it can turn very inefficient with large record sets.

Answer (score 1):

This will only insert records that are not already in `Permission` table by the combination of UserID and Login.  Probably, UserID alone is enough if Login is stored as redundant (not-normalized data).

```
insert into Permission (UserID, perm, Login)
select U.UserID, 0, U.Login
from Users U
left join Permission P on P.UserID = U.UserID and P.Login = U.Login
where P.Login is null
```

The permission matrix is usually expressed in one of two ways:

1. bit mask - but this gets into scalability issues real quick, so your `Perm` field contains a mask of all "allowed" bits
2. UserId - PermissionId - Access (bit). This is what I assume your table has (the tuple UserId/PermissionId) and hence the LEFT JOIN form on two fields.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this will insert only records that do not have a permission record already.

```
INSERT INTO Permission (UserID, perm, Login) 
SELECT u.UserID, 0, u.Login 
FROM Users u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Permission p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
WHERE p.UserID IS NULL
```